# installing old ruby version by using RVM on Ubuntu 20.4

Tags: apt, ruby, rvm

I'm trying to install old ruby version on **Ubuntu 20.4** by using the **RVM** by using the below command

`$ rvm install "ruby-2.1.6"`

Usually I'm got the error

`Installing required packages: bison, libgdbm-dev, libncurses5-dev, libyaml-dev, sqlite3 - please wait Error running 'requirements_debian_libs_install bison libgdbm-dev libncurses5-dev libyaml-dev sqlite3'`

so, When i'm running

`sudo apt-get install bison libgdbm-dev libncurses5-dev libyaml-dev sqlite3`

Also I get the error

```
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done Note, selecting 'libncurses-dev' instead of 'libncurses5-dev' Package libyaml-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source

Package sqlite3 is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source

Package libgdbm-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source

Package bison is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source

E: Package 'bison' has no installation candidate 
E: Package 'libgdbm-dev' has no installation candidate p
E: Package 'libyaml-dev' has no installation candidate 
E: Package 'sqlite3' has no installation candidate
```

How I can fix this issue?

Comment: Edit your question to show the complete output of `sudo apt update`.

Comment: This all the output

Comment: I already fixed it by using the commands: 
`rvm autolibs disable`
`rvm install ruby-2.1.6`